# aiogram, how release menu with button true/false on each response from result of query to database

Tags: python, aiogram

Can you help to create a buttons (true/false) on each of "Request ID".

i'm have a fuctions:

- get_requests() - return of requests from database
- get_request_kb_fab - for generate a buttons on each row with Request ID

But for now, all my fields a button, how i can change a display of that from:

```
Requests:
BUTTON1(Request: 09.01) BUTTON2(Username: User1)
BUTTON3(True) BUTTON4(False)
BUTTON1(Request: 15.12) BUTTON2(Username: User1)
BUTTON3(True) BUTTON4(False)
```

to:

```
Requests:
TEXT(Request: 09.01) TEXT(Username: User1)
BUTTON1(True) BUTTON2(False)

TEXT(Request: 06.09) TEXT(Username: User2)
BUTTON1(True) BUTTON2(False)
```

```py
from typing import Optional
from aiogram.filters.callback_data import CallbackData

class RequestsCallbackFactory(CallbackData, prefix="fabreq"):
    # change to true of false
    action: str
    # confirm
    value: Optional[bool] = None
    # request id from query
    id: Optional[int] = None

from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
user_data = {}
async def get_request_kb_fab():
    data = await get_request()
    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    for row in data:
        builder.row(
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"Requests text: {str(row[1])}", callback_data="request"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text=f"Username: {str(row[2])}", callback_data="username"),
        )
        builder.row(
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="TRUE", callback_data="true"),
            InlineKeyboardButton(text="FALSE", callback_data="false")
        )
    return builder.as_markup()

@dp.message(Command("test"))
async def cmd_get_requests_fab(message: types.Message):
    keyboard = await get_request_kb_fab()
    await message.answer("Requests: ", reply_markup=keyboard)



@dp.message(Command("get_requests"))
async def cmd_get_request(message: types.Message):
    requests = await get_request()
    if not requests:
        await message.reply("No requests found.")
    else:
        request_list = "\n".join([f"Request ID: {request[0]}, Request: {request[1]}, User: {request[2]}" for request in requests])
        reply_message = f"Request List:\n{request_list}"
        await message.reply(reply_message)
        db_shutdown()
```

Response in telegram for get_requests():

```
Request List:
Request ID: 3, Request: 08.08, User: user1
Request ID: 4, Request: 09.09, User: user2
```